# How to get a list of all frameworks that .xcodeworkspace uses for app?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Our app is built using React Native and uses cocoapods, and some of those pods seem to be including certain frameworks e.g., *apptrackingtransparency.framework*. How can I see a list of all the frameworks that the app and its pods are including?

Answer (score 1):

Open your project in XCode and **left side** of the project hierarchy there are two project structure first one is your **project** and the second one is the **pod** file now click on the pod and open a new window just middle of the screen where all **pod** and **framework** listed out

[image: Click here to see]